# Why do I get multiple true and false and I don't get the Result of how many occurence in the list?

Tags: prolog

```
count_element(Element, List, Result) :-    
    count_element(Element, List, 0, Result).    % here I start the real rule with counter initialized to 0

count_element(Element, [], Counter, Counter).    % if it arrives to the end of the list so there isn't any other element, Result is Counter.
count_element(Element, [Head | Rest], Counter, Result) :-    % if Head is Element, Counter increments
    Head =:= Element,
    NewCounter is Counter+1.
    count_element(Element, Rest, NewCounter, Result).    % start recurively the function with the list without the head
count_element(Element, [Head | Rest], Counter, Result) :-    % if head is not the element, simply start recursively maintaining the counter
    Head \= Element,
    count_element(Element, Rest, Counter, Result).
```

I get this:

```
?- count_element(3,[1,2,3,3],R).
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
false.
```

but no Result of how many occurences of that certain Element...

other interesting results:

```
?- count_element(3,[3],R).
true ;
true ;
false.

?- count_element(3,[1],R).
true ;
R = 0 ;
true ;
false.

?- count_element(3,[],R).
R = 0 ;
true ;
false.
```

Comment: `NewCounter is Counter+1.` should be `NewCounter is Counter+1,`

Comment: @Allexj you should be getting singleton warnings when consulting your code. They help you spot errors like the one TessellatingHeckler found.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of singletons. That's a code smell that you're doing something
not quite right.

Also, this evaluates the left-hand side and the right-hand side as arithmetic expressions and compares the results:

```
Head =:= Element
```

whilst this tests whether or not the left-hand side can be unified with the right-hand side.

The one is not the converse of the other.

Prolog has multiple flavours of "equality".

What you probably want are `==/2` and `\==/2` which compare to terms for equivalency, but variables are only equal to themselves. No unification is done (e.g., the variable `A` is only equivalent to itself, it's not equivalant to the variables `_`, `B`, or `C`, and its not equivalent to a atom, term or number).

Rewriting your example (with slightly shorter variable names), we get:

```
count_element( E, Ls, R ) :- count_element( E, Ls, 0, R ) .

count_element( _ , []    , C , C ) .
count_element( E , [H|T] , C , R ) :- H  == E, C1 is C+1, count_element(E,T,C1,R) .
count_element( E , [H|T] , C , R ) :- H \== E,            count_element(E,T,C,R) .
```

We can simplify this by introducing a cut (`!/0`), to eliminate the choice point at `H == E` (the two items, having been found equivalent, are not going to magically become non-equivalent on backtracking).

That gives us this:

```
count_element( E, Ls, R ) :- count_element( E, Ls, 0, R ) .

count_element( _ , []    , C , C ) .
count_element( E , [H|T] , C , R ) :- H  == E, !, C1 is C+1, count_element(E,T,C1,R) .
count_element( E , [H|T] , C , R ) :- count_element(E,T,C,R) .
```

Alternatively, you could use a *soft cut* (`Condition -> Then ; Else` ).
That gives us:

```
count_element( E, Ls, R ) :- count_element( E, Ls, 0, R ) .

count_element( _ , []    , C , C ) .
count_element( E , [H|T] , C , R ) :-
  ( H == E -> C1 is C+1, C1 = C ),
  count_element(E,T,C1,R)
  .
```